# Mercurial: open earlier version of file in an editor?

Tags: mercurial

Is there any way to quickly view an earlier version of a file (at an earlier revision) in an text editor?

Thanks

Comment: `hg revert -r REV FILE`?

Comment: I don't want to revert to versions. I just want to possible open 2-3 versions at different revisions of the same file in an editor to be able to visualize the history of the file better.

Comment: You **must** to revert if you want to have older changeset of single file (or `hg up` the whole WD). If you want to open different for compare 1) use **proper tool** - diff OR 2) create needed amount of clones, update to nneded versions in each 3) open file(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With command line Mercurial:

- `hg cat -r REV -o %s-%r FILE`
- `edit FILE-REV`
- `del FILE-REV`

In TortoiseHG Workbench:

- Select the desired revision.
- Open the *Revision Details* tab.
- Click the document icon (*Show all version-controlled files in tree view*)
- Navigate to the file and right click it.
- Select *View at Revision*.

Or starting TortoiseHG from command line:

- `thg filelog FILE`
- Right click the desired revision.
- Select *View at Revision*.